# Could not convert database value errors

Tags: database

I have this weird error when i try to retrieve some data, the current error is:

```
Could not convert database value to 'array' as an error was triggered by the unserialization: 'unserialize(): Error at offset 6879 of 6884 bytes'
```

What might be triggering the error?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.